# Communiacting between UIDatePicker and UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uidatepicker

In my project I have 3 controllers;

- `NavigationController`
- `ServiceTableViewController`
- `DateTableViewController`

The `ServiceTableViewController` is the initial view controller. It has several rows which prompt the user to enter in data, which will be emailed to a particular email address. One of the rows, when tapped, sends the user to the `DateTableViewController` which prompts the user to select a date from the `UIDatePicker`.

The issue I am facing is getting data back from `DateTableViewController` in order to display a label on the `ServiceTableViewController` to show the date the user selects in the `DateTableViewController`. I know how to get information from one view controller to another, but to go in reverse, so to speak, is not something I know how to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

There are couple of ways to pass data back and forth between view controllers.

- [Delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)
- [Target-Aciton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html)
- [Notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)
- [KVO](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html)

but honestly delegates are really all you need really  and it sounds like in your current case. 
see this -> ([Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers))

---

Having said that, if you use delegates, here is how --- 
setup a protocol in `DateTableViewController.h` at the top like so:

```
@protocol DateTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)userSelectedThisDate:(NSDate *)d;
end
```

put this with the other properties

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DateTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

and in `DateTableViewController.m` with the date to send back

```
[self.delegate userSelectedThisDate:withTheDateToSendBack];
```

in and `ServiceTableViewController.h` add

```
#import "DateTableViewController.h"
@interface ServiceTableViewController : UIViewController <DateTableViewControllerDelegate>
```

and since you are `UINavigationController`, somewhere in `ServiceTableViewController.m` add this when you are about to push to the `DateTableViewController`

```
DateTableViewController *vc = [[DateTableViewController alloc] init];
self.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

and finally put the delegate method in `ServiceTableViewController.m`

```
- (void)userSelectedThisDate:(NSDate *)d {
   NSLog(@"%@", d); // this should show the returned date 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Research delegate pattern ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)) (a heavily used pattern within Apple frameworks). You want to define a delegate protocol which allows to a date to be passed to the delegate.

You could implement the pattern as an @protocol with a single method and a property on the `DateTableViewController`. The `ServiceTableViewController` sets itself as the delegate before pushing the `DateTableViewController`.

Or, you could implement using a block. Again, the `ServiceTableViewController` sets the block before pushing the `DateTableViewController`.